# Why Google does datastore allow duplicated ID/Name? And what is the best practice for managing this?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Ok, now see this code

```
public void insertUser1(){
   public static Key personKey=KeyFactory.createKey("Person", "PersonName");
   Entity userEntity=new Entity("User", "User1", personKey);
   userEntity.setProperty("FirstName","Tom");
   datastore.put(userEntity);
}
```

After ran `insertUser1();`, you can see it in datastore

```
ID/Name - FirstName
User1     - Tom
```

Now, I want to modify firstname of user1 but this time I use this code

```
public void modifyUser1(){
   Entity userEntity=new Entity("User", "User1");
   userEntity.setProperty("FirstName","Mary");
   datastore.put(userEntity);
}
```

Now, check datastore again, I can see 2 entries:

```
ID/Name - FirstName
User1     - Tom
User1     - Mary
```

**Why Google does datastore allow duplicated ID/Name? And what is the best practice for managing this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one have parent, second one doesn't.

```
public static Key personKey=KeyFactory.createKey("Person", "PersonName");
Entity userEntity=new Entity("User", "User1", personKey);
```

have id `Key(Key(Person,PersonName), User, User1)`

but this:

```
new Entity("User", "User1");
```

just `Key(User, User1)`. So it's different ids.

Basically it's entity *Key* that unique per database, and it consists of *Parent Id* (or empty) and *Entity Id*.

Read more about entity parents: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/#Java_Ancestor_paths

Comment: So, **ID/Name** of each User Entity can be duplicated? I thought "**ID/Name**" is always unique?

Comment: no, it cannot. you have two different ids. ids includes parent path, not just entity path. entity id is "parent id + entity id". entities under different parent can have same id (sub id at this case). so it can be `<parent100, child100>` and `<parent200, child100>` (notice, it have different parent ids). but cannot be duplicated `<child100> and <child100>` or `<parent100, child100> and <parent100, child100>`